# How to access parent object during creation (of both objects)?

Tags: c#, oop

In a project here, we have an Object ClassTest, which has many sub objects:

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public bool[] abTestAvailable = new bool[_TESTS];


    public ClassTest_FCT_Extern Test_FCT_Extern = API.Serializer.Load<ClassTest_FCT_Extern>(API.Workstation.strPath_Hardware + "FCT_Extern.xml");
    // ...
```

The idea was now, that `Test_FCT_Extern` sets `abTestAvailable` during initialization:

```
public class ClassTest_FCT_Extern
{
    public bool TestAvailable
    {
        get { return API.Test.abTestAvailable[(int)ClassTest.IndividualTest.FCT_Extern]; }
        set { API.Test.abTestAvailable[(int)ClassTest.IndividualTest.FCT_Extern] = value; }
    }
```

But this fails, because during the creation of the `API.Test objects`, the `API.Test.Test_FCT_Extern` is created. So, in this moment `API.Test` still does not exist and the Array `abTestAvailable` is not yet initialized.

I have found now a solution for our case, but maybe there are smarter ways to access parents parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, the solution was to make the array static:

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public static bool[] abTestAvailable = new bool[_TESTS];
```

The static array is initialized before the Objects are created

```
public class ClassTest_FCT_Extern
{

    public bool TestAvailable
    {
        get { return ClassTest.abTestAvailable[(int)ClassTest.IndividualTest.FCT_Extern]; }
        set { ClassTest.abTestAvailable[(int)ClassTest.IndividualTest.FCT_Extern] = value; }
    }
```

works fine, without exception.
Moral: make static if possible!

Comment: Yes, works like a charm until you decide to make another instance! Why not just initialize it in the constructor? Or in the setter? Plenty of room everywhere!

Comment: Yes, it's no solution if static is not an option for you. I don't understand your suggestion. The problem is, as far as I understand it, that API.Test doesn't exist, not that the array is uninitialized.